# Append data in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to append some data in firebase, but it's getting replaced instead.

I start with:

```
scorching-fire-2211  
  Latlng: "7.00003"
  REGISTER_NO: "13MSE0149"
```

Now when I try to add new REGISTER_NO

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://scorching-fire-2211.firebaseio.com/");
myFirebaseRef.child("REGISTER_NO").setValue("13mse0254");
```

The data becomes:

```
scorching-fire-2211  
  Latlng: "7.00003"
  REGISTER_NO: "13mse0254"
```

The older one is getting replaced, but I want this to be appended to that.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to create a list for `REGISTER_NO`, using `.push()`.

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://scorching-fire-2211.firebaseio.com/");
myFirebaseRef.child("REGISTER_NO").push().setValue("13mse0254");
```

This will maintain a list and look like this in JSON format:

```
{
   "REISTER_NO": {
      "-K6Zjr34pzqjvO9ffwrI": "13mse0254"
   }
}
```

The strange looking string is a the push-id created by the Firebase SDK. If you want your own key, you can specify the `.child()` key:

```
Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://scorching-fire-2211.firebaseio.com/");
myFirebaseRef.child("REGISTER_NO").child("13mse0254").setValue(true);
```

This will create a structure of:

```
{
   "REGISTER_NO": {
      "13mse0254": true
   }
}
```

Then you can retrieve it by going to the path of `/REGISTER_NO/13mse0254`.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped. If so, can you please mark it as accepted? It's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Comment: There is a typo in the block of code. `REISTER_NO": { ...`. I would fix it myself but don't have 2000 rep yet so I would need it approved. And it won't let me do the edit unless I modify 6 characters and well everything else is good in the answer and does not require any other modifications.